# How to control trackball behaviour in Android Views?

Tags: android, view, custom-controls, trackball

I have a FrameLayout view which contains one (MapView-like) control and some additional buttons overlaying it. (the layout xml is below).

I want to allow the user to pan/scroll the main view using not only touch but also the Trackball. 
The problem is - using the trackball just switches the focus between all the controls on the layout, and I cannot seem to find a way to contain the **onTrackballEvent** to just the MainView.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/pageView" 
    xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yappa"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <MainView
        android:id="@+id/mainView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </MainView>


    <ZoomControls android:id="@+id/ZoomControls01"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </ZoomControls>

    <Panel
          ....
    </Panel>

</FrameLayout>

</merge>
```

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `android:focusable` property?

Comment: focusable controls how you go from one control to another. not what i meant in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to override the `dispatchTrackball` in your custom view, and grab the events.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hey reflog, I am in the same situation, can I have a sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

Panning is simply implemented by as mentioned before the focusable property, set your mapview's focusable attribute to true and it will indeed pan the map with the trackball when you have placed the mapview in focus.